# What is the name of this effect and how could I solve it?

Tags: raytracing

I've implemented the algorithm in the paper "Learning the light transport the reinforced way". What is the name of this effect and how should I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a buggy implementation.

Comment: The learning rate was too large. It should be around 0.001. Now everything looks great ! But I still don't know why this happens when the learning rate is large.

Comment: These artefacts look like a bug on the gpu, you sometimes see this if for example you use uninitialised variables or have data races in a compute or pixel shader.

Comment: I don't use gpu or c++. I only use julia programming language and this is just part of my master's thesis.